# Join two tables on a third

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can join two tables on a value but, how do you join two tables with different values using a third that contains both values? Such as:

```
Table A
  CustomerID
  info
  info

Table B
  CustomerName
  info
  info

Table C
  CustomerID
  CustomerName
  info
  info
```

This was my attempt but it failed miserably...

```
select * from [dbo].[table A] a,
    [dbo].[Table B] b
left join [dbo].[Table C] c on c.CustomerID = a.CustomerID
left join [dbo].[Table C] d on d.CustomerName = b.CustomerName
```

Just a point in the right direction would be very helpful.

Comment: Show us what you do for Table A, B and C please.

Comment: there are two info columns in all tables? You need to show all of the table columns

Comment: Don't mix notations.  use left join or `,` but not both.  The Engine isn't able to process both standards.

Comment: You are already getting a lot of answers that we are makign shots in the dark on how to relate tables to one another and what it is you want.  the implicit cross join seems to be one of your biggest issues.  But including more about table schema, example data, and desired result will get you to a more accurate answer.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[table A] a
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Table C] c
 on A.CustomerID = C.Customer_ID
LEFT join [dbo].[Table B] b 
 on c.CustomerName = B.CustomerName
```

This will include all records from A, those that match in B and those that match from B to C.

So the order of the table and the left join matter.. Do you want all records only where they exist in all 3 tables?  all records that exist in A and those that match in B and C? All records that exist in B and only those that match in C and A?

Comment: I am sorry I am new to SQL and have been thrown into the pit with the lions! I know the information was lacking and I apologize and am thankful for all the input. And thank you xQbert!

Comment: @Jeremy I've found the following useful in understanding joins early on: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/  It's a good tool just to get the differences between INNER, Left, Right Full outer, and cross joins.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your query likely "failed miserably" is because you have an `implicit cross join` between `TableA` and `TableB` then 2 left joins.  you are probably wanting an `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` between those tables too.

So:

```
FROM
  TableA, TableB
```

That is the same as writing

```
FROM
  TableA
  CROSS JOIN TableB
```

You likely want to join the three tables more like

```
FROM
  TableA a
  LEFT JOIN TableB b
  ON a.? = b.?
  LEFT JOIN TableC c
  ON a.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
  AND b.CustomerName = c.CustomerName
```

OR

```
FROM
  TableA a
  LEFT JOIN TableC c
  ON a.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
  LEFT JOIN TableB b
  ON b.CustomerName = c.CustomerName
```

Comment: Perhaps we need to go A-->C-->B or B-->C-->A  the reason you can't resolve B's join is I think you have to go though C first.

Comment: @xQbert Perhaps, definitely need more info from OP, but I assume A is the unique CustomerId so the one side of one to many because CustomerId is the only column listed :)

Comment: If I assume A is customer and B is locations which could be shared by multiple customers then C is the associative table which resolves the Many-to-Many.   But yes more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select * from [dbo].[Table C] c
left join [dbo].[Table B] b on b.CustomerName = c.CustomerName
left join [dbo].[Table A] a on a.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
```